# validation form_tag without field from model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

i try to send params from my form_tag, but in input_type i'm not using field from model.

my form_tag code :

```
<%= form_tag(wizard2_path, :method => :post, :multipart => true, :id => "form_wizard") do -%>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Select your bill file</legend>

         <!-- TODO: include a preview of the bill - zurb foundation supports this-->
         <input id="bill" name="bill" type="file" />    
         <!-- TODO: automatically import once selected? -->
         <!-- TODO: display right page after, original content
         <input id="upload_bill" name="commit" type="submit" value="Upload bill" />| <a href="" onclick="$('#no_bill').show();$('#first_bill').hide();">Cancel</a>

         -->
         <div class="large-2 columns" >
             <!-- TODO: make the browse button the zurb class type -->
             <p>
                <%#= link_to "Upload", "#", :onclick => "changeWizard('upload');", :id => "upload_btn1", :class => "button postfix"%>
                <%= button_tag "Upload", :id => "upload_btn1", :class => "button postfix", :onclick=>"bill_upload_validation();" %>
             </p>
         </div>
   </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

please tell me if im wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using fields in a model, you're right to use `form_tag` as opposed to `form_for`.

In the form, you can define your params:

```
<%= file_field_tag :bill %>
<%= submit_tag 'Upload' %>
```

Any validation would have to be in the controller at that point (if you weren't doing anything with the models).